# ASP.NET Переадресация на страницы для авторизованных пользователей с JWT токенами

Tags: asp.net

использую в проекте ASP.NET. Сделал авторизацию с помощью JWT токенов, но не понимаю как получить страницу с использованием JWT токена.

Поясняю:

по адресу **site/auth** пользователь авторизуется, страница доступна для получения БЕЗ авторизации, отправляется JWT токен и записывается в память

по адресу **site/** главная страница, она должна быть доступна только авторизованным пользователям (используется декоратор `[Authorize]`).

Как перенаправить пользователя с адреса **site/auth** на адрес **site/** так, что бы сервер посчитал его как авторизованного пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо авторизации для получения страницы я использовал динамически-загружаемый контент через js на самом сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Вам вместе с запасом надо в заголовке отправлять токен который вы получили при авторизации, т.е если используете bearer в заголовке должно быть что-то типа такого 'Authorization: Bearer {ваш токен}'

Comment: Это понятно, но как сделать это если я перенаправляю пользователя с одной страницы на другую с помощью метода Redirect?

Comment: Можно топорным методом получить в контроллере из Request.Header.Authorization токен и добавить его в Response.Header и сделать редирект